# How to disable theme's player styles so I could use plugin player?

Tags: audio

I'm trying to build online radio website and i'm currently using "Sounder" theme, but the problem was that I couldn't get "now playing" data from the stream. I installed "Shout" HTML5 player and it works perfectly in the players preview mode, sound comes and getting the metadata. When I try to put the shortcode in the site it gets overwrited by theme's player, I can see the player, but it doesn't look like in preview mode.

I tried to block the black player with custom css

".mejs-controls {display: none;}

.mejs-horizontal-volume-total {display: none;}

.mejs-button {display: none;}

.mejs-mediaelement {display: none;}

.mejs-container {display: none;}"

But then nothing comes up. How do I disable it so my plugin player comes?

[image: Upper image is with the plugin i'm trying to import in the site, normal before I press update]

Now I disabled theme's player and added my player to footer, it does take this style for somehow but I can't figure out why and how to disable it do that.

".trx_addons_audio_player {display: none;}"

Comment: You should ask the theme developer, we don't really support 3rd party themes or plugins.

Comment: Ok. I was just wondering that there would've been some command to disallow it to overrun plugins player. I got the theme with Envato Elements subscribtion so I don't have support.